# Android dropping background view color

Tags: android

I've noticed that Android drops the background color of a View for certain colors at certain times.

- #FF0000 works consistently, but sometimes #CACACE is dropped.
- #CACACE is drawn correctly into the background of a view on first install, but if I click run in the eclipse ADT (when program is already installed), then the background color of this view will be dropped (#FF0000 continues to be drawn correctly for some reason).

Maybe this has to do with a) CACACE not being a valid color under a certain scheme android is using?, b) the caching of layout files in the bin folder after the first install?

Here is the code for clarity:

```
<View 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#CACACE"
android:id="@+id/back_ground"
/>
```

This happens to be nested in a relativelayout, but it also happens when in a linearlayout.  This is happening on android 4.1.1 and the particular phone is AT&T ZTE model z992, but I've noticed it on several other versions and phones (some appear not to have the problem also).

Any ideas on what's going on here?  I'm curious because this is such a weird bug.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't see any problem by `View` itself. Most likely you have layers in your layout and the color happens to stack on each other causing it to look different from what you expected.

Comment: I declare the background to be #CACACE in several nested containers.  It seems that maybe this repeating declaration of the same color might be partially something.  Because if I switch anywhere in the chain to a different color to #999999 for example, that will also cause it to behave correctly.

Comment: Looks like the issue has to do with repeat background colors being called in either a) nested, b) overlapping views.  The child view will assume that the parent background is drawn when it may not be or maybe programmatically overridden.  For this reason, the child view will not draw it's own background if it is the same color.  This while potentially conserving resources definitely introduces VERY inconsistent behavior.  A quick fix is to alter the color slightly when the child view shares the same background color.  For instance #FFFFFF would go to #FFFFFE and it will be drawn correctly.